# Error with hreflang tags - no return tags

Tags: html, google-search-console, hreflang

Google webmastertools complains that there are errors with hreflang tags on my site: no return tags, but as I can see it there sure are return tags. Am I missing something, or is webmastertools the problem? On the site are 3 similar pages in 3 languages, and the English page is the default.

Tags on http://www.domainname.nl/en/:

```
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/nl/" rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/en/" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/zh/" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-CN" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/en/" rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Tags on http://www.domainname.nl/nl/:

```
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/nl/" rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/en/" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/zh/" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-CN" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/en/" rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Tags on http://www.domainname.nl/zh/:

```
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/nl/" rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/en/" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/zh/" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-CN" />
<link href="http://www.domainname.nl/en/" rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Comment: the question is vague... you should write down which urls are causing the errors... you can see a list of them in the table below the graph in the section 'International Targeting' of your google webmaster tool

Comment: It says: 'zh-CN' - no return tags, but as you can see in above code, they are there! Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. I would suggest to also add the plain language code for English without specifying the country, so you can target The usa, canada, etc

Comment: So, you would say that webmastertools is the problem, perhaps not updating the info correctly?